# Display a parsed HTML content in ionic app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I retrieve information from JSON file. Title and content are both string type

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('example.json').then(function(resp){
    $scope.title = resp.data.title;
    parser=new DOMParser();
    htmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(resp.data.content, "text/html");
    $scope.content = htmlDoc.body.innerHTML;
    console.log(htmlDoc.body.innerHTML)
  }, function(err){
    console.error('ERR', err);
  })
});
```

But the content is not a simple string, it's a number of html tags (piece of information I retrieve from html page). The thing is I can't parse it in my index.html. When I write content, the view shows plain text or

```
{"location": null}
```

The length of content string is quite big, because as I mentioned above, it consists of plenty of html tags

Maybe I should parse it into markdown

Comment: you'll have to use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) if you plan on working with HTML inside variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Using [angular-marked](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked/) and [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive), I changed my code in this way

```
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $http, marked){
      $http.get('example.json').then(function(resp){
        $scope.title = resp.data.title;
        var markedStr = toMarkdown(resp.data.content);
        $scope.content = markedStr;
      }, function(err){
        console.error('ERR', err);
      })
    });
```

And then in index.html I'm showing the content

```
 <div marked="content">
 </div>
```

Comment: it's giving me failed to instantiate module 'hc.marked'. What are you including please in your app.js? and in your angular.module in the controller.js ?